# make a calculator that calculates the volume of a cube

Tags: python, calculator, cube

I am new to python and my problem is when I want to make a calculator that calculates the volume of a cube:

```
>>> print(int ** 3 (input ("Enter the side length: ")))
Enter the side length: 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    print(int ** 3 (input ("Enter the side length: ")))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: `int` is not a type in Python. Python is Dynamically typed, and therefore there are no ways to define variable types.

Comment: `side_len = int(input('Enter side length: ')); print('The volume of the cube is: ', side_len ** 3)`

Answer (score 2):

The `int()` function should wrap around the whole `input()` function, Something like this

```
print(int(input('Enter the side length:')) ** 3)
```